# django - KeyError when trying to log in

Tags: django, django-sessions

when i try to login it shows :

```
KeyError at /admin/

'loggedin'
```

it shows this error only when i submit with correct username and pwd. so i think it is about my admin view..

here is my log in view :

```
def log_user_in(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        uname = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=uname, password=password)
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if user is not None:
                request.session['loggedin']="djangoo"
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and log out view :

```
def log_user_out(request):
    user = request.user
    try:
        del request.session['loggedin']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/%s/'%(user))
```

and admin view :

```
def admin_view(request):

    if request.session['loggedin'] == "djangoo":
    #other codes..
```

here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^superadmin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$',view='index', name='index'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/post/(?P<postslug>[-\w]+)',view='single_post', name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^login/$', view='log_user_in'), # i log in to admin page from this url
    url(r'^admin/$', view='admin_view', name='admin'),# to this url
    url(r'^admin/logout/$', view='log_user_out', name='logout'),
    url(r'^admin/post/add/$', view='add_post',name='addpost'),
    url(r'^admin/post/edit/(?P<post_id>\d+)', view='edit_post', name='editpost'),
    url(r'^admin/post/delete/(?P<post_id>\d+)', view='delete_post', name='deletePost'),

)
```

Comment: use `if request.session.get('loggedin') == 'djangoo':`

Comment: Have you activated the `SessionMiddleware`?

Comment: yes i activated. and one more thing. this error is not always shown.i get this error sometimes. now i changed it to request.session.get() .

Comment: get() will try to fetch the key value and if the key is not there, it will just return an empty string. post your urls.py and mention when you're getting this error.

Comment: @drTerminal much better to post error tracebak, but obviously error is coming from `if request.session['loggedin'] == "djangoo":`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you logged out, you manually delete `request.session['loggedin']` key, and when you browse to admin page, `request.session['loggedin']` fails because you already delete that key.

You can control if `request.session` has `loggedin` key with:

```
`loggedin` in request.session
```

So, writing your admin view like:

```
def admin_view(request):

    if `loggedin` in request.session and request.session['loggedin'] == "djangoo":
    #other codes..
```

Or simply use

```
if request.session.get('loggedin') == 'djangoo'
```

as @Alexander Larikov said

EDIT: I need to mention that, it is good to check if a key exists in dictionary or dictionary-like structure, especially if you also may delete that key in somewhere else.